# The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST. with laravel

Tags: php, laravel

[image]i want to add a post in my blog so when i just click on the button submit to add the post i get this error :

```
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.
```

this is the form :

```
 <form action="/add" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf_field
    @method('POST')
    <label for="">Titre de l'article</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id=""  placeholder="Titre de l'article">
    <label for=""> Description de l'article</label> </br>
    <textarea name="description" id="" cols="63" rows="20"></textarea> 
    <label for="">Image pour l'article</label>
    <input type="file" name="photo" class="form-control" id=""  placeholder="Titre de l'article">
    <input type="hidden"  class="form-control" name="articlemed" value="{{$med->ID}}" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Ajouter l'article </button>
    </form>
```

and this is the controller :

```
public function add (Request $request)

    {
        $blog= new blog;

        $blog-> title = $request->input('title');
        $blog ->body = $request->input('description');
        $blog->author_id=$request->input('articlemed');
        $blog ->image = $request->input('photo');
        $blog-> save();
        return back()->withSuccess(Success!' ) ;
```

and finally the web.php

```
Route::get('/index','specvil@index');

Route::get('/inscription', 'specvil@inscription');

Route::post('/ajouter','doctor@ajouter');

Route::post('/bienvenu','doctor@authentification')->name('aziz');

Route::get('/edit/{id}','rendezv@edit');
Route::post('/update/{id}','rendezv@update');

Route::get('/blog' ,'postcontroller@index');

Route::get('/blog_{post}' ,'postcontroller@show' );

Route::post('blog/{getid}/store', 'commentcontroller@store');

Route::post('/add', 'postcontroller@add')->name('newpost');
```

Comment: If I were you, I will change to `Route::get('/add', 'postcontroller@add');` to check is it I'm redirect to this route correctly, secondly `@method('POST')` is kind of redundant in your HTML.

Comment: I've already change it but i got the same error

Comment: can you try it with action={{url('add')}}

Comment: @MekjkrhG same error

Comment: can u check your php artisan route:list

Comment: @MekjkrhG  i didn't found the route in the list

Comment: @ghofran your routes might be cached try `php artisan route:cache`

Comment: i got this : Route cache cleared!

Comment: i run it again and still error

Comment: @ghofran does the route appear in the list now? is it still the same error?

Comment: no the route don't appear @MekjkrhG

Comment: If the route is not there, you are not redirect to this `/add` route, it might be route cache, or the route is redirect to another route action, example you have route like this `/{route-name}` or you double-assigned the route name. Your code is fine here, check other possiblity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please use this once .

```
php artisan cache:clear,
php artisan route:cache,
php artisan view:clear,
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: you have any duplicate route same as this route??

Comment: No there is not i'm sure

Answer (score 2):

Which Laravel version, you are using ? 
Also, I tried your code, and it works, Try as the guys said, clear your cache using

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

and

```
php artisan route:clear
```

Also, try to remove the @csrf_field, and replace it only with @csrf, 
And remove also @method('POST'), because it's not needed. 
Finally, double check your web.php

Answer (score 1):

Change your route to Route::post('/add', 'postcontroller@add')->name('add');
And then in your form action

```
<form action="route('add)" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

and also remove  @method('POST')

Comment: same problem :(

Comment: Did you check your route list php artisan route:list?

Comment: yeah and i didn't found him

Comment: can you post your web.php and route:list result

Comment: i add it to my post you can check it

Comment: also route:list resutl please

Comment: i add it to the post so you can check it now

Comment: php artisan optimize:clear and see if add route is added if not try composer install and confirm if route is added

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot.

`<form action="{{ route('newpost') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

**or**

Remove the named route

```
Route::post('/add', 'postcontroller@add');

<form action="{{ url('/add') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```